# VBA, How to set a name for a range valid in all sheets of the book?

Tags: vba, excel, range, cell

I have muuliple sheets and I want to copy, say, "A2" in one sheet and paste the value (or formula that the cell contains) in other sheets. I use this code, but VBA highligts yellow the "cell.Select" line.
How to solve it, do you know?

```
Sub test()

Set cell = Range("a2")

cell.Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("one").Activate
cell.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("two").Activate
cell.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Thanks
Nikolay

Answer (score 0):

When you set the cell to a given range, you don't need to select it. Instead you can reference it. If you also set the worksheet objects you wish to eventually paste it into, the above could then be written in a more condensed and direct manner, without selects:

```
Sub test()

    Set cell = Range("A2") 'implicit reference to activesheet in activeworkbook

    Set ws1 = Sheets("one") 'requires that you have a sheet named "one" in the activeworkbook
    Set ws2 = Sheets("two") 'requires that you have a sheet named "two" in the activeworkbook

    'assign the value to somewhere in the ws1 and ws2
    ws1.Range("A2") = cell
    ws2.Range("A2") = cell

End Sub
```

EDIT:

version using copy, to retain formulas

```
Sub test()

    Set cell = Range("A2") 'implicit reference to activesheet in activeworkbook

    Set ws1 = Sheets("one") 'requires that you have a sheet named "one" in the activeworkbook
    Set ws2 = Sheets("two") 'requires that you have a sheet named "two" in the activeworkbook

    'assign the value to somewhere in the ws1 and ws2
    cell.Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A2")
    cell.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A2")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    Dim cl As String
    cl = Range("a2").Address
    Range(cl).Copy Destination:=Sheets("one").Range(cl)
    Range(cl).Copy Destination:=Sheets("two").Range(cl)
End Sub
```